# How to know the allocation method of process in Linux?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system

I would like to know how process decide either buddy allocation or [slab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation). Is there any command to find this out? And How does it know that which allocation should it use?

Answer (score 0):

Allocator used by the Linux kernel is defined by *configuration*:

- CONFIG_SLAB - SLAB allocator
- CONFIG_SLUB - SLUB allocator
- CONFIG_SLOB - SLOB allocator

Check `/boot/config-*` file for configuration of specific kernel.